# Check if object is instenace of Child class based on Base class

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

I'm trying to check if the object is an instance of some class but it doesn't work. Here is my simplified code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() { }
    virtual ~Base() { }
};

class Child : public Base
{
public:
    Child(int something) { }

    void Method()
    {
        throw Exception(this);
    }
};

class Exception
{
public:
    Base* subject;
    Exception(Base* base) : subject(base) { }
};

/* ---------------------------------------------------- */

try
{
    Child ch(1);
    ch.Method();
}
catch (Exception& ex)
{
    // the exception is thrown in Child class
    // therefore pointer to Child object is passed as an argument
    // to Exception's contructor so I'd expect folowing statement to be true
    // but it isn't

    if (Child *child = dynamic_cast<Child *>(ex.subject))
        std::cout << "subject of the exception is Child" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "subject of the exception is just Base" << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: Why don't you just write `if (dynamic_cast<Child *>(ex.subject))`

Comment: `ex.subject` is not valid in the `catch` block because it was already destructed. So it caused undefined behavior

Comment: @Danh I have more complex code behind this, where I'd like to use that `child` variable - this is just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ex.subject` is not valid in the catch block because it was already destructed. So it caused undefined behavior.

Here I see two Solutions:

**1) If you just Need to know which class caused the error:**

```
class Exception
{
public:
    std::string subject;
    Exception(const std::string &base) : subject(base) { }
};
```

And in child:

```
void Method()
{
    throw Exception("Child");
}
```

**2) If you need the object that threw the exception:**

You create the child object before the try block

```
Child ch(1);
try
{
    ch.Method();
}
catch (Exception& ex)
{
    // the exception is thrown in Child class
    // therefore pointer to Child object is passed as an argument
    // to Exception's contructor so I'd expect folowing statement to be true
    // but it isn't

    //Do something with ch
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but (according to the second option) what if Child's constructor throws an exception?

Comment: @MartinHeralecký You can create a second Exception class which is thrown from the constructor. This second exception is based on my first example

Answer (score 1):

To fix your example, put the construction of your object before the "try" block. The objects destructor is called if it is declared inside the block.

```
Child ch(1);
try
{
    ch.Method();
}
```